# How does del operator work in list in python?

Tags: python, list, del

I have read the `python docs` for `list` and how the `del` operators works, but I need explanation for the following behavior

In this case, `c` and `l` points to the same object(list), so doing changes on one affects the other, but deleting one does not delete the object. So what happens here? Is it just the `pointer` to the list object is lost?

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> c = l
>>> c.append(4)
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> del c
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

#### Deletion by slice operation

```
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> del l[::2]
>>> l
[2, 4]
```

`l[::2]` returns the new list. but `del l[::2]` does in-place deletion. So in this case, is not a new list being returned? What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`l` and `c` are *bound* to the same object. They both are references to a list, and manipulating that list object is visible through both references. `del c` *unbinds* `c`; it removes the reference to the list.

`del l[::2]` removes a specific set of indices *from the list*, you are now operating on the list object *itself*. You are not unbinding `l`, you are unbinding indices **inside** of the list.

You can compare this with retrieving and setting values as well. `print c` is different from `print c[::2]` and `c = something` is different from `c[::2] = something`; the first of both examples accesses just the list object, or assign a new value to `c`, the latter examples retrieve a slice of values or set new values to the sliced indices.

Under the hood, `del c` removes the name `c` from the dictionary handling all variables (`globals()` gives you a reference to this dictionary). `del l[::2]` calls the [`__delitem__` special method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) on the list, passing in a `slice()` object.

Comment: I understand `print c` is different from `print c[::2]` because in the latter case, a new list object is returned. Now your explanation for `__delitem__`, passing the slice object makes perfect sense. but wondering, the corresponding indices have to de-reference those items, before shifting elements to the left..correct?

Comment: That is correct; those indices are references that are being removed from the list.

Comment: `print c[::2]` is translated as `c.__getitem__(slice(None, None, 2))`, which can return whatever it likes.  A `list` returns a new list with values, yes.