# When does slicing operator create a shallow copy in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to ask you for help about the behaviour of a slicing operator in Python.

1. On the one hand we know that
   `L[:]`
   creates a shallow copy of the list `L`. To verify it one can just print
   `id(L), id(L[:])`
   and notice that they are different.
2. On the other hand we know that
   `del L[:]`
   removes references from the original object. It makes the original list empty - not the shallow copy of it. Of course I agree that creating a shallow copy, then removing references from it, would make little sense so I understand that here we want to operate on the original list.

Is there any rule saying when slicing operator creates a shallow copy and when it doesn't? How can I know it without manually testing it?

I searched for this and found these topics:

- [How does del operator work in list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847149/how-does-del-operator-work-in-list-in-python)
- [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

but unfortunately they do not answer my question, at least I do not see it.

Comment: "Is there any rule saying when slicing operator creates a shallow copy and when doesn't?" Yes. It always creates a shallow copy.

Comment: The behaviour of `del L[:]` is independent of that of `L[:]` because the former translates to `list.__delitem__(slice)` while the latter is `list.__getitem__(slice)`.

You can verify this by creating a class with `__getitem__` and `__delitem__` and then getting and deleting a slice.

Comment: In Python, `L[:]` calls `L.__getitem__`, while `del L[:]` calls `L.__delitem__`. In other words, `del` completely changes meaning of the statement.

Comment: First of all thanks Vincent for editing my post. Right after sending it I edited it and tried to make it better, but you were so quick I didn't make it in time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`del L[:]` is a distinct operation from accessing `L[:]`, which is again a distinct operation from `L[:] = x`.

- `del L[:]` calls `__delitem__` on the object with a `slice` object.
- `L[:]` calls `__getitem__` with that `slice` object.
- `L[:] = x` calls `__setitem__` with the `slice` object and `x`.

These three operations can be implemented in very different ways, depending on what the object is. For built-in list types, `__delitem__` erases the items specified in the slice, `__setitem__` replaces the items with the items given, and `__getitem__` returns a *new* (copied) list consisting of the elements specified.

However, not all objects have to behave this way. For example, with a NumPy `array`, `__getitem__` with a slice returns a *view* of the array rather than a copy - modifying the view alters the original array.

Comment: Thanks nneonneo for your help. Your answer exactly concerns what I needed to know to understand what is happening in this case.