# pytorch delete model from gpu

Tags: gpu, pytorch, allennlp

I want to make a cross validation in my project based on Pytorch.
And I didn't find any method that pytorch provided to delete the current model and empty the memory of GPU. Could you tell that how can I do it?

Comment: I need to do the same thing because I want to train some models (one after another) in the same process. You found the answer?

Answer (score 23):

Freeing memory in PyTorch works as it does with the normal Python garbage collector. This means once all references to an *Python-Object* are gone it will be deleted.

You can delete references by using the [`del`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847149/how-does-del-operator-work-in-list-in-python) operator:

```py
del model
```

You have to make sure though that there is no reference to the respective object left, otherwise the memory won't be freed.

So once you've deleted all references of your `model`, it should be deleted and the memory freed.

If you want to learn more about memory management you can take a look here:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-memory-management

Comment: Does moving models/tensors/losses to cpu with eg: `model.cpu()` remove them from GPU?

Comment: @drevicko Not directly, but when you delete all references to the GPU `model` it should be freed automatically. This works like with all other Python variables.

Comment: hmm.. ok.. I find that a little odd.. I guess torch wouldn't have to re-allocate it's memory on GPU if you send it back, but if you want to keep it's values (eg: on cpu or pass them to another GPU) and don't need it on the original GPU any more, you'd want a way to free that memory.

Comment: @drevicko You can take a look [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cpu):
"Returns a copy of this object in CPU memory." (if not already on CPU). Like said above: if you want to free the memory on the GPU you need to get rid of all references pointing on the GPU object. Then it will be freed automatically. So assuming `model` is on GPU: `model=model.cpu()` will free the GPU-memory if you don't keep any other references to of model, but `model_cpu=model.cpu()` will keep your GPU model.

Comment: Ah, yes. Makes sense. Might be handy to mention that you can free GPU memory with `model.cpu()` IF that's the only reference to its GPU data. Likely others will have a similar use case to me (ie: want to keep the data but get it off GPU). Incidentally, would backprop info retain a reference?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to follow the below steps rather than just doing `del model_object`

```
model_object = My_Network().cuda()

del model_object  #deleting the model 


# model will still be on cache until its place is taken by other objects so also execute the below lines
import gc         # garbage collect library
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```