# Pytorch fails with CUDA error: device-side assert triggered on Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, tensor

I am trying to initialize a tensor on Google Colab with GPU enabled.

```py
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

t = torch.tensor([1,2], device=device)
```

But I am getting this strange error.

```bash
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1
```

Even by setting that environment variable to 1 seems not showing any further details.
Anyone ever had this issue?

Comment: you should factory reset your notebook and then try.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

While I tried your code, and it did not give me an error, I can say that usually the best practice to debug CUDA Runtime Errors: device-side assert like yours is to turn collab to CPU and recreate the error. It will give you a more useful traceback error.

Most of the time CUDA Runtime Errors can be the cause of some index mismatching so like you tried to train a network with 10 output nodes on a dataset with 15 labels. And the thing with this CUDA error is once you get this error once, you will recieve it for every operation you do with torch.tensors. This forces you to restart your notebook.

I suggest you restart your notebook, get a more accuracate traceback by moving to CPU, and check the rest of your code especially if you train a model on set of targets somewhere.

To gain a clearer insight into the typical utilization of GPUs in PyTorch applications, I recommend exploring deep learning projects on GitHub. Websites such as [repo-rift.com](https://repo-rift.com) can be particularly useful for this purpose. They allow you to perform text searches with queries like "How does this paper use GPU". This can help you pinpoint the exact usage of CUDA in specific lines of code within extensive repositories.

Comment: Shape mismatch. It is quite a shame that torch doesn't tell you the error though

Comment: I receive this error, what is the problem? File "/home/tf/.virtualenvs/torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2824, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

Comment: Great. I switched to CPU and the error in now clear!

Comment: I am sorry to ressurrect this. but I  am facing the same issue but when I run in CPU the error does not happen. Is there any other procedure I can try to find out what is happening?

Answer (score 10):

Bumped into the same issue when using Transformers **Trainer**.
In my case, the issue was caused by **model input and tokenizer length sizes mismatch**.
Here's what solved the issue for me:

```
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

and mismatch was caused when adding `pad` token:

```
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '<pad>'})
```

Answer (score 8):

As the other respondents indicated: Running it on CPU reveals the error. My target labels where {1,2} I changed them to {0,1}. This procedure solved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

**1st time:**

Got the same error while using simpletransformers library to fine-tuning transformer-based model for multi-class classification problem. simpletransformers is a library written on the top of transformers library.

I changed my labels from string representations to numbers and it worked.

**2nd time:**

Face the same error again while training another transformer-based model with `transformers` library, for text classification.
I had 4 labels in the dataset, named 0,1,2, and 3. But in the last layer (Linear Layer) of my model class, I had two neurons. `nn.Linear(*, 2)*` which I had to replace by `nn.Linear(*, 4)` because I had total four labels.

Comment: What is a "string representation"? Do you mean one-hot vector?

Comment: For example, I have a sentiment analysis problem with two labels, "Positive" and "Negative". I changed my labels from "Positive" to 1 and from "Negative" to 0, in my data. This is what I mean by "changing labels from string representation to numbers."

Comment: I am facing this problem with an Extractive QA task.  Dis anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: I am trying to fine-tune mistral 7B on kaggle T4x2 GPUs and facing the same problem. The video(tutorial) I'm following is working okay on colab A100. My code (almost same) is giving me this error.

Comment: Mistral 7B is LLM which is different. You can post your question with proper details.

Answer (score 3):

Double-check the number of gpu. Normally, it should be gpu=0 unless you have more than one gpu.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Colab as well.
If your code runs normally on device("cpu"), try deleting the current Colab runtime and restart it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe, I mean in some cases**

It is due to you forgetting to add a sigmoid activation before you send the logit to BCE Loss.

Hope it can help :P

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is an open-ended question for most people who land on this page because the underlying issue is different in each case. In my case the error appeared on Colab when I tried to run this notebook on Colab pro: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SRclU2pcgzCkVXpmhKppVbGW4UcCs5xT?usp=sharing at `supervised_finetuning_trainer.train()` step.

If there's someone like me who could not bring the computation into CPU instead of GPU (mostly because the error stack-trace led to a different package like transformers, ..., leading all the way back to pytorch), here's the approach to get a more accurate stack-trace:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/ad78d9597b224443e9fe65a94acc8c0bc48cd039/docs/source/en/troubleshooting.md?plain=1#L110

Credits: sgugger on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and found the reason, because the vocabulary dimension is 8000, but the embedding dimension in my model is set to 5000

Answer (score 0):

I am coming from the VQGAN+Clip "ai-art" community. I get this error when I already have a session running on another tab. Killing all sessions from the session manager clears it up, and let's you connect with the new tab, which is nice if you have fiddled with a lot of settings you don't want to lose.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I first tried to run my computations on the CPU to detect the actual issue.
It turned out that my image transforms were wrong I was applying some un-necessary transformation to my mask image

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar error, and the problem was with the label mismatch only! My train set and test set had different label counts and thus, this error was coming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while fine tuning a tiny autoregressive model.  The problem was caused in the dataloader where I was adding "-100" to the last position of the lable tensor.

```
labels[:, -1] = -100  # Typically, -100 is used to ignore the loss calculation at specific positions
```

I removed this line and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

A full restart with new memory fixed it in Jupyter Notebook on my own server, perhaps it also helps if you are on Colab (untested):

- Run `!smi-nvidia`,
- find the PID that you work on, like 123456,
- run `!kill -9 123456` (see [How can I fix this strange error: "RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374935/how-can-i-fix-this-strange-error-runtimeerror-cuda-error-out-of-memory)),
- and the kernel restarts on its own,
- and the error is gone.

I guess this means the same as [the other answer about restarting the runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73205676/11154841), just done on your own.