# Getting "RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory" when memory is free

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to run a test code on GPU of a remote machine. The code is

```
import torch

foo = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
foo = foo.to('cuda')
```

I'm getting the following error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/remote/blade/test.py", line 3, in <module>
>     foo = foo.to('cuda')
> RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
> CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
> For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
> ```

From [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374935/how-to-fix-this-strange-error-runtimeerror-cuda-error-out-of-memory/67617190#67617190), the conflict between cuda and pytorch versions may be the cause for the error. I run the following

```
print('python v. : ', sys.version)
print('pytorch v. :', torch.__version__)
print('cuda v. :', torch.version.cuda)
```

to get the versions:

> ```
> python v. : 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58)
> [GCC 7.5.0]
> pytorch v. : 1.11.0.dev20211206
> cuda v. : 10.2
> ```

Does anything here look off?

Comment: The Pytorch build you are using requires CUDA 10.2

Comment: @talonmies Is this a question or a statement? b/c you see that I have tried w/ 10.2 with no luck. If this is a question, I have no preference on cuda version. PS why you think this question should not have cuda tag?

Comment: It is statement. `torch.version.cuda` is a hard coded string which emitted by the Pytorch build. It must match a set of runtime libraries accessible in the default library search path. And your PyTorch problems aren’t a CUDA programming related question, which is why I have removed the tag

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So I removed the "EDIT:" section. Still, the problem remains with pytorch v. : 1.11.0.dev20211206 and cuda v. : 10.2. Is there anything else that I can check?

Comment: @Blade Did you solve it?

Comment: @Minions I added an answer for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*To answer the comments that asked if I was able to address the issue:*

I had this issue in two separate occasions,

1. First time, I was trying to use `conda` libraries while I had python packages in another directory as well (probably installed using `pip`). I ended up manually removing the other library.
2. The second time the issue arose from zombie processes: essentially I had prematurely terminated the code and hence the GPU memory was not emptied. The solution was to run

   ```
   ps -elf | grep python
   ```

   and then kill the processes using

   ```
   kill -9 [pid]
   ```

   where `[pid]` is the process id returned after the first command.

Comment: Thanks @Blade! so you just killed all the python processes?

Comment: @Minions Yeah. Basically, I was not running anything but it was showing python processes, that's why they call them zombie processes. They just occupied memory.

Comment: Ah ok. In my case I don't have any running processes, but thanks for your answer :)