# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory for VQGAN-CLIP error

Tags: python, pytorch, out-of-memory

I have this error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 114.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.13 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 4.27 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I have absolutely no idea why id be getting this error I have a rtx 2060 max-q with 6 GB memory, heres the line I run:

```
python generate.py -p "The never ending void" -s 480 480
```

And the output:

https://pastebin.com/avZm9P7j

Heres a picture

[Picture of traceback error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX7NT.png)

If thers any way to fix this please let me know

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374935/how-to-fix-this-strange-error-runtimeerror-cuda-error-out-of-memory ?

Comment: Its similar but all the answers for that one didnt work for me

Comment: You can give details of batch-size, model and output of `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: @Spedungis if those answers didn't work, what happened when you tried them? Can you include your code and what you get when you try the answers on the other page?