# Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 5.93 GiB total capacity; 4.63 GiB already allocated; 23.19 MiB free; 4.85 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to run train pytorch model

this is my config file batch size, I have tried reducing batch_size to 1 but the same error

```
local batch_size = 3,
local num_batch_accumulated = 4,
```

This is the output of ***nvidia-smi***

[image]

As we can see only 451 mib is allocated out of 6144 Mib

I have tried following different solutions mentioned in stackoverflow post here but not able to solve this.

[How can I fix this strange error: "RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374935/how-can-i-fix-this-strange-error-runtimeerror-cuda-error-out-of-memory)

Comment: Please, provide some additional information. What kind of model are you trying to train? Are you running training in Jupyter notebook or as a python script? What output does torch.cuda.is_available() give you?

Comment: I am trying to run following git project https://github.com/dmirlab-group/sadga error occurs on https://github.com/dmirlab-group/sadga#step-2-training